# Почему браузер не может получить данные через fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch

При получении данных через fetch локально с браузера выдает ошибку blocked by CORS policy, сам запрос такой

```
fetch('апи', {
        headers: {
            'X-AUTH-TOKEN': 'ключ',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(response => console.log(response))
```

при запросе через postman все работает,
при запросе через retrofit в приложении на андроид тоже все работает,
почему браузер ругается на cors?

Comment: Можно конечно попробовать добавить mode : 'cors'. Но не уверен, что поможет.

Comment: не помогает к сожалению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В браузерах работает политика CORS - механизм, когда браузер отправляет дополнительный запрос серверу, с "вопросом" можно ли выполнить ваш изначально задуманный запрос.

Ваша проблема в том, что сервер не разрешает данные заголовки, по этому надо настроить именно сервер. Реализацию не подскажу, все зависит от того на чем он написан, но в целом можно ориентироваться на  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: через postman (прога для проверки рест апи) все работает, также в приложении андроид все работает через retrofit

Comment: cors - чисто браузерная особенность. В целях безопасности браузер не дает отправить запрос на сервер с другим URL, пока сервер не даст согласие

Comment: да, уже понял что именно браузер блокирует